# HTML/CSS Multiple images overlapping

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to make is 2 images of arrows/pointers overlap a banner (another image).

How can I make the 2 arrows stay "on" the image and align them to the middle left and second one middle right?

Here's an image of what I've got for now:
http://prnt.sc/b8govy

And the code I'm using (for the image above):

```css
img#art {
display: block;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
max-height: 300px;
z-index: -1;

}

img#raw {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    z-index: 2;
}

img#law {
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
     
     <img id="raw" src="images/rightarrow.png">
     <img id="law" src="images/leftarrow.png">
     <img id="art" src="images/banner.png">

    </div>
```

Comment: try to take display:block off first, that makes every element take all the available space of the parent element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `position absolute` in the arrows and `relative` in parent.

```css
.banner {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.arrow.left {
  top: 50%;
  left: 15px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 15px solid #000; 
}

.arrow.right {
  top: 50%;
  right: 15px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 15px solid transparent; 
  border-left: 15px solid #000; 
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="arrow left"></div>
  <div class="arrow right"></div>
  
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x200/?text=Banner">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get the arrows on the banner but i'm having trouble putting them in the middle left/right of the banner, any suggestions ?

Comment: Yes, read the code in my answer, you have to use top: 50%, margin-top: - (half of the height), and margin-left or margin-right (depends of what arrow are you styling) to separate them from the parent borders.

Answer (score 1):

- remove all `display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto`.
- use `position: relative; z-index: -1;` on banner.
- move it up with `top: -Xpx;`. // or other unit (vh, rem, em)
- both arrows `z-index: 2`
- left arrow `float: left`
- right arrow `float: right`

here's a fiddle with random pictures from the web
https://jsfiddle.net/warkentien2/xLo1ac5e/

Comment: You're right. I would've guesses at least inline-block. Thanks!